# Error when trying to fit the model Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to apply cnn to images data but I keep getting this error when I try to fit the model "ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)."

I have dataframe with two columns one column have array of normalized data of images and the second column have label of the data

```
print(type(feature_test))
print(type(feature_train))
print(type(feature_val))
print(type(class_train))
print(type(class_test))
print(type(class_val))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print(type(feature_test.values[1]))
print(type(feature_train.values[1]))
print(type(feature_val.values[1]))
print(type(class_train.values[1]))
print(type(class_test.values[1]))
print(type(class_val.values[1]))

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>

print(type(feature_test.values[1].shape))
print(type(feature_train.values[1].shape))
print(type(feature_val.values[1].shape))
print(type(class_train.values[1].shape))
print(type(class_test.values[1].shape))
print(type(class_val.values[1].shape))
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>

feature, feature_test, class_, class_test= train_test_split(df["data_of_image"],df["label"],test_size=0.2,train_size=0.8)
feature_train, feature_val, class_train, class_val = train_test_split(feature,class_,test_size = 0.25,train_size =0.75)
model = Sequential()
 
    # Defining The Model Architecture
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (224, 224, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Dense(224, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(5, activation = 'softmax'))
 
    # Printing the models summary
model.summary()

early_stopping_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = 15, mode = 'min', restore_best_weights = True)
 
# Adding loss, optimizer and metrics values to the model.
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'Adam', metrics = ["accuracy"])
 
# Start Training
model_training_history = model.fit(x = feature_train.values, y = class_train.values, epochs = 50, batch_size = 4 , shuffle = True, validation_split = 0.2, callbacks = [early_stopping_callback])
```

Comment: Why are you passing object dtype array(s) to a function that expects numeric data?

Comment: What do you mean by normailzed?  Are all the images the same shape?   Examine `feature_train.values` - what's the shape?  the dtype?

Comment: I mean when I read the image I saved the nromalized the data of the image so an array of an image [1 ,3 ,4][4,5,8][3,5,2] is divided by 255. My feature_train.values are array([array([[[0.18823529, 0.18431373, 0.10588235],
               [0.21960784, 0.21568627, 0.1372549 ],
               [0.24705882, 0.24313725, 0.16470588],
               ...,
               [0.20784314, 0.20784314, 0.14509804],
               [0.20784314, 0.20392157, 0.14901961],
               [0.21176471, 0.20784314, 0.15294118]],